# analyze customer support tickets to understand product gaps/features

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, classification, product

I am looking to analyze customer support tickets to understand product gaps/features or what enhancements I can make in my product to address customer pain points/issues.

But like you know customer support tickets have lot of text/notes in them that have been collected via email or phone by our support agents and it has been humanly impossible to to through all the tickets and understand the big picture.

I am looking from ideas from the developers in stack overflow on how to handle this problem of analyze customer support tickets to understand product gaps/features or customer pain points.

Could you please point me in the right direction? Can we use NLP or any other ML concepts to get a handle on the problem?

Comment: fyi: the `ml` tag is not for machine learning.

Comment: ok, thank you for correcting